# Exporting to File leaving out newline characters

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project and I have to export data from my SQL Server 2008 r2 database to text file. The client requires each line to have `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` at the end. Part of my code calls a user-defined function to concatenate parts of the data I am trying to get.

Here is my main script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CAST('01' AS CHAR(3))+
CAST(CUSTOMERNAME AS CHAR(10))+
dbo.GETORDERS(CUSTOMERNNUMBER) + 
AST('03' AS CHAR(3))+       
CAST(ISNULL(ADDRESS_LINE,'') AS CHAR(30))+
CAST(ISNULL(CITY,'') AS CHAR(20))+
CAST(ISNULL(UPPER(STATE),'') AS CHAR(2))+
CAST(ISNULL(ZIP,'')AS CHAR(10)) 
FROM TABLE1
```

Below is my function `GETORDERS` code. The function takes in a parameter, `@CUSTOMERNUM`.

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(max) = ( SELECT
            CAST('02' AS CHAR(3)) +
            CAST (LEFT(ORDER_FIELD1,40) AS CHAR(40)) +
            CAST (LEFT(ORDER_FIELD2,40) AS CHAR(40)) +
            CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
        FROM [ORDER_TABLE] ord
        WHERE CUSTOMERNUM = @CUSTOMERNUM
        FOR XML PATH(''))

SET @output = REPLACE(@output,'&#x0D;','')
```

I can run the script, get the results for the query to the grid, copy/paste into NotePad++ and the return characters show up just fine. See the first screenshot. Noticed that all the lines have the characters.

[image]

Now if I use query to file or use the Import/Export wizard to run the code. In NOTEPAD++, the return characters do not show for the part that was generated by the function. See the second screenshot.

[image]

So why does the only one of the return characters show up only when using the Import\Export Wizard or query to file? I could just 'select all' and copy/paste, but there is so much data being generated that I get 'out of memory' exception. If I could come up with a way to automate this by either query to file or using the import/Export Wizard that would save me a lot of time. Plus, I am curious as to what is causing the issue.